# VBA Save/Export extremely huge images

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint

I'm making a comic saving program with Powerpoint VBA.

I already made image downloader from internet site, and it was successful.

The problem was the image's size.

The size of image was too huge, so it wasn't able to save images with `.Export` property.

Is there any way to save extremely huge images without Resolution loss?

+if it is not able to save big images, please tell me merge multiple images without Resolution loss in VBA instead.

- Code

`

```
Public Sub downWebtoonS(ID As Long, S As Long, F As Long)
On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Long, ldBar As Double
ldBar = ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("loadA").Left
For i = S To F
Call downWebtoon(ID, i, S, F, i)

Call ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes("res").Export("C:\temp\PPT\Webtoon\img" & i & ".png", ppShapeFormatPNG) 'It is the problem

ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes("res").Copy
ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes("res").Delete
ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("loadA").Width = (ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Width - (ldBar * 2)) / (F - S + 1) * (i - S + 1)
ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("nowStatA").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (i - S + 1) & " / " & (F - S + 1) & " (" & Int(100 / (F - S + 1) * (i - S + 1)) & "%)"
Next i
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 0
wsh.Run "cmd /k title PPT & color 1F & echo. Wait a minute... & del C:\temp\PPT\Webtoon\tmp.png & exit", vbHide, waitOnReturn
End Sub


Public Sub downWebtoon(ID As Long, viewNo As Long, S As Long, F As Long, t As Long)
On Error Resume Next
Dim n As Long, i As Long, URL As String, shpTop As Double, ldBar As Double
ldBar = ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("load").Left
Dim shp As Shape
shpTop = 0
n = getImgNo(ID, viewNo)
For i = 0 To n - 1
DoEvents
With ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    .Name = "shp" & i
    .Line.Visible = False
    .Top = shpTop
End With
Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes("shp" & i)
URL = getURL(ID, viewNo, i)
shpTop = shpTop + downImg(shp, URL)
If i > 0 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes.Range(Array("shp" & i, "frm" & i - 1)).Group.Name = "frm" & i
Else
ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes("shp0").Name = "frm0"
End If
ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("load").Width = (ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Width - (ldBar * 2)) / n * (i + 1)
ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("nowStat").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = i + 1 & "Cut / " & n & "Cut" & " (" & Int((i + 1) / n * 100) & "%)"
ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("loadA").Width = (ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Width - (ldBar * 2)) / (F - S + 1) * ((t - S) + ((i + 1) / (n)))
ActivePresentation.Slides(mainS).Shapes("nowStatA").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = (t - S + 1) & " / " & (F - S + 1) & " (" & Int(100 / (F - S + 1) * ((t - S) + ((i + 1) / (n)))) & "%)"
DoEvents
Next i
ActivePresentation.Slides(TmpS).Shapes("frm" & n - 1).Name = "res"
End Sub



Public Function downImg(shp As Shape, link As String)
Call DownloadFile(link, "C:\temp\PPT\Webtoon\tmp.png")
shp.Fill.UserPicture "C:\temp\PPT\Webtoon\tmp.png"
shp.Width = WidthImage
shp.height = LoadPicture("C:\temp\PPT\Webtoon\tmp.png").height * (WidthImage / LoadPicture("C:\temp\PPT\Webtoon\tmp.png").Width)
downImg = shp.height
End Function
```

Comment: Show the code you tried. Check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing here from just your description. It's always best to show us the code you're having trouble with.  But if you're using the Slide.Export method, look at the help entry for it. By specifying height and width, you can have it export images at up to around 3000 pixels in PPT 2010 and before, and at much higher resolutions in PPT 2013 (updated) and 2016

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I'll add it.

Comment: Exporting Shapes doesn't work predictably. Try setting a temporary presentation's slide size to the same proportions as the image, insert the image onto the slide then use .Slide.Export (with height and width parameters) to export the image.